# How do I print NULL string using integer

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void)
{

    unsigned int pqr = 201;
    unsigned int def = 113;

    printf("The values are,%u,%s,%s,%u\n", pqr,"\0","\0",def);
    printf("The values are,%u,%d,%d,%u\n", pqr,atoi("\0"),atoi("\0"),def);


}
```

**The values are,201,,,113

The values are,201,0,0,113**

The first printf gives me nothing if the value string is set to NULL and I used format specifier "%S". How do I achieve the same result using format specifier %d in the second. Currently it gives "0" instead of nothing.

Comment: `"\0" != NULL`. `"\0"` is just an empty string (for all string purposes, it's equivalent to `""`).

Comment: What do you expect to get from printing `'\0'`? 'NULL' string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first printf gives me nothing if the value string is set to NULL and I used format specifier "%S".

`""` is the empty string. `"\0"` is an empty string with an additional  null character. It is not the same as `NULL`. Passing a null pointer for the `s` conversion specifier is undefined behavior.

> How do I achieve the same result using format specifier %d in the second.

You cannot. `printf` with `%d` conversion specification prints an `int` value; it cannot print nothing.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` always prints an integer, and therefore always prints *some* sequence of digits. There's no concept of a `NULL` integer, and so you can't make it print nothing.

By the way, `"\0"` is not a `NULL` string; `NULL` is. `"\0"` is, for all string purposes, equivalent to `""`.

Comment: all *string* purposes. I'm aware there are differences.

Answer (score 0):

Just test if its 0 and print what you want if it is.

```
{
    int number = 0;
    char dummy[24];
    printf("This is the number: %s\n", (number == 0)? "" : itoa(number, dummy, 10));
}
```

The ternary operator (`? :`) should check if the number is zero, and if it is, return an empty string that gets printed.

If the number is not zero, it will run `itoa`  (Integer to Ascii) on the number (base 10), and return that string.

For `itoa` to work, it needs a buffer to store its result in, hence the `dummy` variable.

Answer (score 0):

the `atoi()` function convert string to integer so that why it print `0` in the second case because the `atoi` of the null string (`"\0"`) is 0 and the atoi of a random string, which is not number, is `0` too.

the `%d` is used to display integer and the `%s` is used to display strings